# HTML5 with Web Services

Tags: iphone, web-services, html, cordova, html5-video

Now the case, I want to develop a iPhone apps/web apps using Phonegap. Ok, imagine the app can do all sort of thing include data processing, transaction, login, video streaming, display data from the web services, so to do this I need use JavaScript (Ajax) to call the web services, then only put it into the HTML?

HTML5 now come with support of video right? For example, once I get the video data from the Web Services, then I use Javascript to insert into the video tag and HTML5 will handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes on all counts.